# HTML/JavaScript/PHP: How do I get a web button to make images cycle through a directory?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a directory with images like

```
/Web/ex1_1.png
/Web/ex1_2.png
/Web/ex2_1.png
```

and I have written HTML and JavaScript to set up two canvas elements, one for `ex1_1.png` and one for `ex2_1.png`, and each canvas element paired with a button so that when the first is clicked the canvas erases and re-draws with `ex1_2.png`.  I want, on the next click, for the program to realize there's no next image in the sequence and cycle back to the start, `ex1_1.png`.  I haven't had success with other approaches to this problem, so I'm now trying to have PHP scan the directory and provide a list of files.  However, I don't understand how to make PHP send the JavaScript the information.  In my JavaScript file I have included

**JavaScript**

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("get", "../php/request.php", true);
req.send()
console.log(req);
```

and I have a PHP file named request.php

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(scandir("../Web/"));
?>
```

The console prints a pretty empty looking XMLHttpRequest and I'm sure I'm thoroughly misunderstanding some principle of how these things relate to each other, but until yesterday I had no experience with PHP and none of the resources I could find told me how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

My previous snippet was missing an ; after the closing ?> in the javascript block.  Sorry for that oversight.

I've decided to test my new solution and everything is solid now.  Because this question is compound and only enough information has been given to solve the early issues.  Please edit your title to something like "**Create a json string from array of image files in a remote directory**" or similar.  For support on any later issues, please post a new non-compound question.

I have a file called canvaswriter.php:

```
<?php
/* *** Server structure used during testing:
/test
    /folder
        canvaswriter.php
        request.php
    /Web
        ex1_1.png
        ex1_2.png
        ex2_1.png
*** */  

$path="../Web/";
include("request.php");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images=<?php echo json_encode($pngs); ?>;
    console.log(images);
</script>
```

I wouldn't personally write an include for what is essentially two lines of code to harvest files from the server, but for your specific case you may want to handle all of the javascript on the include too.  I don't know where the rest of the magic is going to take place.

Here is request.php:

```
<?php
echo "Build array of .png images from directory files:<br>";

//$files=array_diff(scandir($path),array('..','.'));    // no filetype filter
chdir($path);   // set correct directory for glob()
$pngs=glob("*.png"); // with filename pattern filter

print_r($pngs);
?>
```

The page will display:

> Build array of .png images from directory files:
>
> Array ( [0] => ex1_1.png [1] => ex1_2.png [2] => ex2_1.png )

The source code will display:

```
Build array of .png images from directory files:<br>
Array (
    [0] => ex1_1.png
    [1] => ex1_2.png
    [2] => ex2_1.png
) 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images=["ex1_1.png","ex1_2.png","ex2_1.png"];
    console.log(images);
</script>
```

and the console will display:

```
["ex1_1.png", "ex1_2.png", "ex2_1.png"]
```

And finally, I don't understand why you are writing these images to a canvas.  Are you converting these .png images to base64 and then writing them to the canvas?  Is there a reason you can't use them as-is and cycle them?  Seems like unnecessary extra work, but again I don't have all the information.  I hope this sufficiently solves your issue and helps you to move forward with your project.

Comment: and if you need pattern matching to filter the files down to only .png images, then glob() may be more helpful than scandir().

Comment: This looks like what I want but when I use it I get an error saying that it expected an express but got a <.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but I have the script in an external file.  I only typed the part from `var ...` to `... images);`

Comment: about the external file, it is not necessary, unless there is noticeable load time impact.

Comment: I still get the same error.  I have it in an external script not for speed but because I'll ultimately want to use this script on several pages and would rather not have to insert the HTML repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code -

**PHP (request.php)**

```
$files = scandir("../Web/");
$pngOrJpg = [];
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if (stripos($value,'.jpg') || stripos($value,'.png')) {
        $pngOrJpg[] = $value;
    }
}
echo json_encode($pngOrJpg);
```

> **Note:** Only getting `.jpg` and `.png` type images array.

**Javascript**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "../php/request.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

> From above code, you can get the `JSON` array like -

```
['ex1_1.png','ex1_2.png','ex2_1.png']
```

Now, Use and manipulate this JSON array with your code.

Comment: So this avoided errors for me but provided none of the images in the console.  I suspect the issue is the directories I'm sending different functions to.  I have the images and HTML in `/Web/`, the JavaScript in `/js/` and the PHP in `/php/`.

Comment: Use full path of the script for scanning directory images. Example :
`scandir("/var/www/html/Web/");` @Addem

Comment: Browse `request.php` from Server. Example : `http://localhost/Web/request.php` from browser. And make sure `scandir()` function get the correct path. Also check the `xhttp.open("GET", "../php/request.php", true);` is requesting `request.php` correctly.  @Addem

Comment: Hm, gave all file functions full file paths and still it's not printing anything.  It may be worth commenting that I'm using the VIM text editor and it doesn't do any syntax highlighting for PHP except where I wrote the `=>` it highlights the `>` in red.

Comment: Ahh! I see! Use `var_dump(scandir("../Web/"))` in `request.php` file and browse it from Server. And check if everything is Ok or Not. @Addem

Comment: And try using `alert(xhttp.responseText);` instead of `console.log(xhttp.responseText);` @Addem